# App icon not showing on iPad Pro(12.9 inch) 2nd Generation

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad app, in AppIcon asset inside .xcassets, I've selected iPad as the only option from attribute inspector.

I've assigned images to all the sizes required including 1024pt for appStore.
The app icon is working for all devices except iPad Pro (2nd generation).

I've updated my Xcode to latest version 9.1 & updated my cocoapods gem to latest version 1.3.1 as mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003).

Issue can be observed on home-screen of both simulator & device, (both running iOS 11).

I've not idea what's going wrong here, may be it's a bug from Apple or they have not added support for this device yet. Any help would be appreciated.